# Sort Imap mails Based on arrival date

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I am using IMAP protocol to fetch mails from Google server using java mail. Mails I retrieved are listed in descending order. How do I retrieve the most recent mail first based on arrival date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Messages are stored as they arrive.  The highest numbered message should be the most recent.  Just access them in reverse order.

Comment: Messages are stored as they arrive *in the folder*. If you move messages from one folder to another via your mail client, the highest-numbered message will be the one most recently added to the folder, not necessarily the most recently received.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply reverse the for loop order, start the for loop as

```
for(int i=messages.length -1; i>=0;  i--){}
```

Hope it helps